# UIPath Automation: Is it possible to perform click and UI interactions in cloud server in UI Path?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

So I have created an xaml flow which clicks browser buttons downloads files and then does some basic operations. I setup a windows server and connected remotely to it and when I debug my process automation while staying on the screen it works smoothly, problem is that I can't keep my pc on forever so when I just minimize the file even though my system remains up and running:
[image]
The UI Path process kills as the button press times out. I was just curious to know if it's compulsory to keep screen up for the ui based process automation to run through or is there a way to initiate the process and then close the screen and let the system do its job?

This is the eror I get which is like first UI interaction:

[image]

Here are the steps I have performed:

1. Created an unattended robot with machine as the remote instance name.
2. Created an environment and connected with the robot created in step 1.
3. Setup UIPath Assistant using machine key and URL.
4. Published the files and then created the process in cloud console.
5. Ran it from cloud console.

The process faults at its first UI interaction. Even though it was running in unattended robot form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for UiPath Studio 20.4 or higher**

For my Use Case Picture in Picture mode worked correctly. Thanks @kwoxer for the suggestions, though his answer was enough but I am adding it up here for those who may need future reference.

So **If you're facing issues with automating user interactions in dynamic JavaScript Website over a cloud server that loads on demand (When you minimize or close your remote session, the process times out as it's not able to find the UI component)**, here are the simple steps to follow:

Goto Debug options on top and select picture in picture as shown below:

[image]

This basically lets the bot start the system from another node. Now when you run the system and even close the remote connection, the automation process including all sorts of UI interaction will work like charm. Please let me know in case someone faces the issues with the same. Would love to help!

Comment: But anyway the PIP is in my eyes just a workaround. In our company we do not use it and it works also when we leave the session. But good it works now. But maybe also mention that PIP is just available in UiPath Studio 20.4 or higher.

Comment: I guess it works well for the static websites, like amazon.in or something that don't load data on demand (React or Angular Websites) because when I tried to scrap a static webpage minimizing and closing worked well, but when I switched to dynamic webpage (Angular one) it stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK this is intended by the licensing model of UiPath. So to solve the issue you need a license for the VM of your RDP connection that allows the unattended usage.

Another idea could be to start the process in the PIP (picture-in-picture) mode. But I have never tested that, so this might also not work.

But maybe you already have a license like that and could test that out.

These are our **types**:
[image: Types]

Comment: I am pretty much sure that I have the license but not sure how to activate it for unattended usage.

Comment: Also can you explain how to proceed for this: AFAIK this is intended by the licensing model of UiPath. So to solve the issue you need a license for the VM of your RDP connection that allows the unattended usage.

Comment: I added an image about our VMs. So please check what type your VMs have.

Comment: Have added the steps as you suggested. That didn't work as well. Have added the steps that I followed from documentation of UIPath. Everything runs fine except for the UI interactions which fail.

Comment: Just have a look on your own portal. You can find it here https://cloud.uipath.com/YOURTENANT/portal_/licensing

Comment: Thanks @kwoxer. My problem is solved using PIP mode, have added a reference answer for others to look through in future.